# I am using entity frame work db first, i want to store connection string in keyvault and need to access from code using app settings from the c# code?

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework-6, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I am using entity frame work db first, i want to store connection string in keyvault and need to access from code using app settings from the c# code

i am able to get the value but for connection string it through an error like
initial catalog is not a key word

Comment: You should give  a little more information if you want an accurate answer. Anyhow, if you're using Visual Studio you can use the connect to db feature and after connecting you can get the connectionstring from the properties. Then you can be at least sure your connectionstring is alright.

Comment: i am able to get the connection string from keyvault but i'm retrieving the string at the time of unity configuration and assign to db context at the time context.database.connectionstring getting error.

Comment: If any demo code for how to get the connection string and how to configurate it will be better. We also could [remote debug the webApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug).

Answer (score -1):

One option is to put the whole connection string attribute (under the connectionString -> Add connectionString="the connection string to save") as a secret to key vault.

Then you should expose a constructor that accepts DbConnection which is passed to the DbContext base class - you can do it in either the template (tt file) or as a partial class.

Then create a factory method at the partial class that:

1. Reads the connection string from KeyVault
2. Instantiate an SqlConnection from that connection string
3. Create your Drived DB context class - passing the Sql Connection
4. return the dbContext